# NVidia 3-way SLI with 4 monitors

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, sli

I need some help with the correct (or preferred) configuration for plugging in 4 monitors to a 3-Way-SLI setup.

I would like to have 3 primary monitors all working in an SLI configuration for gaming/desktop etc, but the 4th monitor to be separate from the SLI configuration. So when doing anything in full screen, the 4th monitor is always available for whatever you want.

```
                  _________
                 |   4th   |
        _________|_________|_________
       |  1-SLI  |  2-SLI  |  3-SLI  |
       |_________|_________|_________|
```

I have 3 NVidia cards presented inside the computer, NVidia Control Panel can see them and I am able to configure SLI.

The 4th monitor however gets turned off as soon as any form of SLI is enabled.

What should I be doing in terms of plugging which monitors into which cards? Do they all go into one card via a means of DVI and DP? Or do I spread the connectivity over all available cards?

Appreciate some help.

Thanks,

Comment: You do realize that most full-screen applications capture all input and minimize on focus loss, right?

Comment: Absolutely, however, it is useful to have a screen available when in this mode. I've used it like this before, just can't seem to get the configuration correct with the NVidia setup.